# Função __autoload do PHP não abre subpastas

Tags: php

Tenho uma função __autolader que deve pegar a pasta ['Conn','etc'], porém a mesma não funciona no meu ambiente Ubuntu 14.04 Lamp, e funciona bem no Windows 7 WAMP. Já fiz vários debugs sem resultado, como resolver esse problema?

```
function __autoload($Class) {

    $cDir = ['Conn'];
    $iDir = null;

    foreach ($cDir as $dirName):
        if (!$iDir && file_exists(__DIR__ . "\\{$dirName}\\{$Class}.class.php") && !is_dir(__DIR__ . "\\{$dirName}\\{$Class}.class.php")):
            include_once (__DIR__ . "\\{$dirName}\\{$Class}.class.php");
            $iDir = true;
        endif;
    endforeach;

    if (!$iDir):
        trigger_error("Não foi possível incluir {$Class}.class.php", E_USER_ERROR);
        die;
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar problemas com o tipo de barra, você pode usar a constante pré-definida [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/dir.constants.php) dessa forma:

```
foreach ($cDir as $dirName):
    if (!$iDir && file_exists($file = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dirName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $Class . '.class.php') && !is_dir($file)):
        include_once ($file);
        $iDir = true;
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Isso garante compatibilidade entre sistemas diferentes...

<sub>Um viva ao Windows que aceita qualquer tipo de barra!!! \o/</sub>

Answer (score 2):

OK! Conseguir solucionar!
Invertendo as barras!!
Fica a dica!

```
foreach ($cDir as $dirName):
        if (!$iDir && file_exists(__DIR__ . "//{$dirName}//{$Class}.class.php") && !is_dir(__DIR__ . "//{$dirName}//{$Class}.class.php")):
            include_once (__DIR__ . "//{$dirName}//{$Class}.class.php");
            $iDir = true;
        endif;
    endforeach;
```

Comment: poderia usar a função realpth() para "canonicalizar".

Comment: Quase lá... Canonizar ^_^

Comment: @DanielOmine quase lá² : [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.realpath.php) xD

Comment: haha desculpe, não sabia como escrever em português, por isso coloquei entre aspas.

Answer (score 2):

Se você não quer mais ter problemas com esse tipo de situação eu recomendo o uso de um AutoLoader pronto. Minha dica é utilizar o AutoLoader do [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), para isso você tem que instalar o mesmo.

## Instalando o Composer

Para instalar o Composer basta rodar uma linha de comando, mais nada! Tem outras maneiras de instalar o Composer, mais vou mostrar a que eu mais gosto.

Execute o seguinte comando na raiz do seu projeto:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Ou

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

Lembrando que se você que utilizar a segunda opção você tem que executar o PHP para isso coloque a pasta dele em variáveis de ambiente ou passe o caminho dele na hora de executar o comando.

Pronto agora você está com o Composer instalado no seu projeto! Agora só precisamos pedir para ele instalar as dependências em seu projeto e ao instalar as dependências ele irá instalar um AutoLoader automaticamente.

## Instalando as dependências

Primeiro você tem que ter o arquivo de configuração do Composer. Na raiz do seu projeto crie o seguinte arquivo:

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "fabio/autoload",
    "description": "Ensinando Autoload",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Fábio Lemos Elizandro",
            "email": "fabio@elizandro.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": ""
        }
    },
    "require": {}
}
```

Veja que eu não declarei nenhuma dependência pois estou somente interessado no AutoLoader. Após criar este arquivo execute o seguinte comando na raiz do seu projeto:

```
$ php composer.phar install
```

Ou

```
$ php composer.phar update
```

Isso vai depender da sua intenção.

## Configuração alternativa

Você pode configurar o AutoLoader do seu projeto, uma configuração que eu utilizo é a seguinte:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
```

Agora eu posso deixar meus códigos fontes dentro do diretório sem precisar incluir o mesmo no namespace.

## Utilizando o AutoLoader

Vou deixar um exemplo de utilização simples que é um index.php instanciando uma classe

Classe de exemplo

```
//src/Response.php
class Response 
{
    private $content;

    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }
    public function flush()
    {
        echo $this->content;
    }
}
```

Index

```
//index.php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

$response = new Response();

$response->setContent('teste');
$response->flush();
```

**NOTA:** Esse mini tutorial é válido para PHP >= 5.3, não sei como é o comportamento para versões mais antigas

Comment: Faltou o mais importante: `require_once('vendor/autoload.php')` na página pública que irá executar sua aplicação. Ou a ideia é expor todo o código da aplicação na pasta pública? É interessante usar uma implementação pronta, só que é mais interessante ainda conhecer como ela funciona.

Comment: Nota: se não for trabalhar com códigos que precisem funcionar em versões do php sem suporte a namespaces (< 5.2) [prefira usar](https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2014/07/send-psr0-to-the-standards-farm-in-the-sky) a [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Comment: @gmsantos realmente esqueci de colocar o exemplo

Comment: @gmsantos nunca utilizei PHP menor que 5.3, então coloquei uma nota no final da resposta. Obrigado

Comment: Mesmo com a edição, prefira o psr4 ao invés do psr0.

Comment: @gmsantos removido comentário sobre psr